# Javascript create nested Keys from Values under eachother & save to a new .json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have been racking my head to solve this.
Assuming we have the below CSV

```
const csv=[
"col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6", 
"frequency,Weekly,haha,U45,A,WEEKLY", 
"frequency,Every two weeks,def,hel,B,BI-WEEKLY", 
"Time,Monthly,ghi,Tar,C,MONTHLY", 
"Time,Every two months,oiu,60T,D,BI-MONTHLY", 
"type,Quarterly,ppp,Q12,E,QUARTERLY", 
"type,Half yearly,qwf,Y34,F,SEMI-ANNUALLY"]
```

what i am trying to do is **create the nested json,** which is not working in addition to that to get the below in a new **json file, named with the value of col1**.
meaning grouping all rows with a common col1 in a single file like below.
if col3, col 4 are the same & col5 & col6 are different the nest should be as below. drop col2.

```
{
  "haha": {
    "U45": {
       "A": "Weekly"
       "B": "Semi-annually"
    }
  }
}
```

what i have done so far is this.

```
const attrs = csv.splice(0,1);
function nested (obj, path, value) {
  let lastKeyIndex=path.length-1;
  lastKeyIndex.map(i => {
    let key = path[i];
    if (!(key in obj)) {
      obj[key]={}
    }
    obj=obj[key]
  })
  obj[path[lastKeyIndex]]=value;
}
csv.map(line => {
  let [col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6] = line.split(',')
  let obj={}
  
  nested (obj, [col3, col4, col5], col6)
  return obj
})
```

your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to create a new file for each distinct value of `col1`? Are you using node and `fs`?

Comment: I am using node. Yes in addition to the nested json in each of those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the node [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) plugin to save the different files. I've marked the lines that you should uncomment in the node environment with `// node only`.

What I've done is loop through `col3` - `col6`, check if the property exists in the parent object, if not create a new object, and then use that to check for the children. If you are on the last property, instead of creating a new object, use `col6`.

```js
// const fs = require("fs"); // node only

let csv = [
    "col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6",
    "frequency,Weekly,haha,U45,A,WEEKLY",
    "frequency,Every two weeks,def,hel,B,BI-WEEKLY",
    "Time,Monthly,ghi,Tar,C,MONTHLY",
    "Time,Every two months,oiu,60T,D,BI-MONTHLY",
    "type,Quarterly,ppp,Q12,E,QUARTERLY",
    "type,Half yearly,qwf,Y34,F,SEMI-ANNUALLY"
];

csv.splice(0, 1);

function addProperty(root, pathList) {
    var lastValue = pathList.splice(pathList.length - 1, 1)[0];
    pathList.forEach(function (path, index) {
        var obj = root[path];
        if (!obj) {
            obj = (index === pathList.length - 1) ? lastValue : {};
            root[path] = obj;
        }
        root = obj;
    });
}

function jsonText(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => value, 4);
}

var files = csv.reduce(function (result, line) {
    var [fileName, , ...pathList] = line.split(",");

    var fileInfo = result[fileName];
    if (!fileInfo) {
        fileInfo = {};
        result[fileName] = fileInfo;
    }

    addProperty(fileInfo, pathList);
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(jsonText(files));

// for (var path in files) fs.writeFileSync(path + ".json", jsonText(files[path])); // node only
```